# Symfony session/routing handling issue

Tags: php, symfony, request

I have used a bundle for some while, later I removed it, as always the composer has updated dependencies after remove process, such as:

```
  - Removing pagerfanta/pagerfanta (v2.1.2)
  - Removing easycorp/easyadmin-bundle (v1.17.22)
  - Updating doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1 => 1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/annotations (v1.6.1 => v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/routing (v4.1.3 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.11.0 => v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/mime (v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/http-foundation (v4.2.7 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v1.1.7): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.2.7 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating psr/log (1.1.0 => 1.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/debug (v4.2.7 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/http-kernel (v4.2.7 => v4.3.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/finder (v4.2.8 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v1.1.8): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/dependency-injection (v4.2.7 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/config (v4.2.7 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/contracts (v1.0.2 => v1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/event-manager (v1.0.0 => 1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/collections (v1.6.1 => 1.6.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/cache (v1.8.0 => 1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/persistence (v1.1.0 => 1.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/doctrine-bridge (v4.2.7 => v4.2.12): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0 => 1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.3.5 => 1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/dbal (v2.9.2 => v2.9.3): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.10.2 => 1.11.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating setasign/fpdi (1.6.2 => v2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating mpdf/mpdf (v7.1.5 => v8.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/inflector (v4.2.8 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/property-access (v4.2.7 => v4.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v1.1.7): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/translation (v4.2.7 => v4.3.9): Loading from cache
```

After this update, a logged in user is being logged out in an hour event when I see that session config is such:

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 1036800
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1036800
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 100
```

these are the local values not master.

The actual problem is that after successful sign login, browsing on the web withing 1h I get logged out. The problem becomes when I navigate to some other page, the response I get is 403 forbidden and the request subscriber logs me out. Perhaps I guess because the user token is not being loaded at the moment and it defines it as expired.

Keep in mind that I use RedisSessionHandler and also there is a subscirber on onKernelController 
which tracks every pre request to controller to identify if user session is not expired and so on. Also, only master requests are being taken into process.

Does anybody have ideas why this might happen? I think this might be influenced by symfony/routing package update.

Comment: My guess is the problem is either in your `onKernelController` subscriber or is an issue with the version of `ReidSessionHandler` not being compatible with the version of Symfony. I seriously doubt the symfony/routing package has this serious of a bug, but who knows.